# Forcing a linebreak in itemize: Two-line bullets

Tags: lists, line-breaking, itemize, enumitem, bullets

This is hard to describe but I think the easiest way is to write out the TeX that I had hoped would work:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[some text \\ more text] Here is some content for the first bullet that will extend onto multiple lines. 
%
\item[first line of bullet \\ second line of bullet] Here is some content for the second bullet that will extend onto multiple lines. 
\end{itemize}
```

Basically, I am using custom text for the bullets themselves, and I would like this text to break into two lines. If I used the code above, the bullets are forced into a single line.

Since the previous example doesn't actually stretch onto multiple lines, here is an example that will:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[some text \\ more text] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis nec fringilla nisi. Nullam 
vel vehicula dolor, accumsan aliquam enim. Nunc arcu quam, tincidunt quis ullamcorper nec, malesuada 
a orci. Nam felis lectus, pulvinar id venenatis sed, ultrices ut elit. 
%
\item[first line of bullet \\ second line of bullet] Cras iaculis dui in purus tincidunt, a imperdiet massa laoreet. Mauris vel pulvinar lacus.
 Integer pharetra neque at turpis pretium, eu pretium sapien lacinia. Etiam commodo urna lacus, non 
ullamcorper enim tincidunt at. 
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I don't understand whay you use  `itemize `to insert a two-line text in the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems more description than itemize:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\leftmargini{4cm}
\renewcommand\descriptionlabel[1]{%
\smash{\parbox[t]{\leftmargin}{\normalfont\bfseries #1}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[some text \\ more text] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis nec fringilla nisi. Nullam 
vel vehicula dolor, accumsan aliquam enim. Nunc arcu quam, tincidunt quis ullamcorper nec, malesuada 
a orci. Nam felis lectus, pulvinar id venenatis sed, ultrices ut elit. 
%
\item[first line of bullet \\ second line of bullet] Cras iaculis dui in purus tincidunt, a imperdiet massa laoreet. Mauris vel pulvinar lacus.
 Integer pharetra neque at turpis pretium, eu pretium sapien lacinia. Etiam commodo urna lacus, non 
ullamcorper enim tincidunt at. 
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: note this will not behave well if the multi-line label goes past the bottom of the page, you may need to force a `\clearpage` before an item to get a page break in a good spot.

Comment: Accepting this answer since it solves the problem, but there is one caveat: When used in conjunction with the enumitem package, the description environment gets some odd spacing and indentation and no longer replicates your output. I tried poking around the enumitem documentation and could not find a working solution. Any ideas how to replicate your output with enumitem loaded?

Comment: @JackRobinson if I load the package then use `\begin{description}[labelsep=0pt]` I think it's OK

Comment: Thanks! This fixes the horizontal indentation (which I thought was \itemindent based on the manual...), but unfortunately does not fix the vertical space between the first line of the "Lorem ipsum..." and the item label.

Comment: @JackRobinson `\renewcommand\descriptionlabel[1]{%
\smash{\parbox[t]{\leftmargin}{\normalfont\bfseries\leavevmode#1}}}`  (just added `\leavevmode`)